# Service Worker registration error: Unsupported MIME type ('text/html')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, service-worker, create-react-app

I'm using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) with an [express](https://github.com/expressjs/express) server.

`create-react-app` has a pre-configured ServiceWorker that caches local assets (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#making-a-progressive-web-app).

The problem I encountered when I tried to publish on my server is that the `service-worker.js` file was available, but I was getting errors in my browser console when it tried to register it.

On Firefox, I got this error:

> Error during service worker registration:
>
> > TypeError: ServiceWorker script at `https://example.com/service-worker.js` for scope `https://example.com/` encountered an error during installation.

On Chrome, I get the more descriptive error:

> Error during service worker registration: DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').

Sure enough, if I look in the Network tab of my developer tools and search for the `service-worker.js` file, I can see that it has the wrong MIME type in the HTTP headers.

I could not understand, though, why it has the wrong MIME type?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Applying this change:

```js
'/service-worker.js'  // ❌
'./service-worker.js' // ✅
```

fixed my issue.

<sub>(in `navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')`)</sub>

---

Or maybe you need:

```
'%PUBLIC_URL%/serviceworker.js'
```

*Thank [@DanielLord](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5129542/daniel-lord) for [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49566059/service-worker-registration-error-unsupported-mime-type-text-html/54211500?noredirect=1#comment125423210_54211500).*

Comment: THIS is the correct answer. The MIME Type error is the result of a file not found.

Comment: Mine took changing it to "%PUBLIC_URL%/serviceworker.js".  But you made me realize that it was the path that was wrong, not the MIME Type

Comment: What a dumb error message O.o

Answer (score 34):

In my Express server application, I have one wildcard (asterisk / *) route that redirects to `index.html`:

```
// Load React App
// Serve HTML file for production
if (env.name === "production") {
  app.get("*", function response(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

This is a very common design pattern. However, it means that any requests for unknown text files initially get redirected to `index.html`, and therefore return with the MIME type of `"text/html"`, even if it's actually a JavaScript or SVG or some other kind of plaintext file.

The solution I found was to add a specific route for `service-worker.js` *before* the wildcard route:

```
app.get("/service-worker.js", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "service-worker.js"));
});
app.get("*", function response(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"));
});
```

Now, when the browser looks for `service-worker.js`, Express will return it with the correct MIME type.

(Note that if you try adding the `service-worker.js` route after the wildcard, it won't work because the wildcard route will override.)

Comment: Please what should I specify if my `index.html` file is in client/public folder and not just a public folder ?  I try this `res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "public", "service-worker.js"));` but it returns A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.

Answer (score 26):

I think that the service worker file is not present at `http://localhost:3000/service-worker.js` so the server is returning index.html instead. Then the registration function has no idea of what to do with a index.html file and tells you that the MIME-type is not correct.

A quick fix would be to copy the service-worker.js file to the `public` folder so that when you hit `http://localhost:3000/service-worker.js` you see the file in the browser.

Remember to go to ChromeDev > Applications > ServiceWorkers and hit Unsubscribe. in order to remove the errored one. Remember also disable cache

Comment: If you can't reach your  /public/service-worker.js. That it somewhat always renders index.html, be sure to check your vhost configuration if you have one. My co-workers added rules that was making the SW.js file impossible to serve because of redirection rules.

Answer (score 9):

ServiceWorker supported MIME type are 'text/javascript', application/javascript and application/x-javascript. go to your server file and set

```
    response.writeHead(201, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

In case, you're working on NodeJS, serviceWorker file should place at public folder.
If you're using Webpack to export serviceWorker to public, you need to use 'copy-webpack-plugin'.

Answer (score 4):

I use nginx to serve react app and I resolved this issue adding mime types to nginx:

```
http {
    include    mime.types; // <--- this line

    # another config details
}
```

Also you can find [mime.types file here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/)

Answer (score 4):

When running webpack dev server, it renders default index.html for missing resource.

If you use your browser to load `http://localhost:3000/sw.js`, you will actually see a rendered react app (started by the index.html). That's why the mime type is html, not javascript.

This fallback to index.html is designed to support *SPA* with front-end routes. For example `/product/123/reviews` has no such html file in backend, the JS SPA app takes care of it in front-end.

Why your file is missing? I guess you created that file in the root folder of your project.

**Webpack dev server doesn't serve from that root folder.**

#### Move your sw.js into public/ folder of your project, it will be served up as expected.

Answer (score 2):

React: 
 public/index.html

```
<script> 
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('sw-cached-site.js', function() {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js', {
        scope: '/',
      });
    });
  } 
  window.process = { env: { NODE_ENV: 'production' } };
</script>
```

Note: Full app/site
public/sw-cached-site.js

```
const cacheName = 'v1';
self.addEventListener('activate', (e) =>{
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(cache => {
          if(cache !== cacheName) { 
            return caches.delete(cache);
          }
        })
      )
    })
  )
});
self.addEventListener('fetch', e => { 
  e.respondWith(
      fetch(e.request)
        .then(res => {
            const resClone = res.clone();
            caches
                .open(cacheName)
                .then(cache => {
                    cache.put(e.request, resClone);
                }); 
                return res;
        }).catch(err => caches.match(e.request).then(res => res))
  );
});
```

Comment: What does this have to do with React?

Comment: Work without connection

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the service worker file is generated (Chrome DevTools -> Sources -> Filesystem). You may receive such an error if the service worker file is not generated at all (check your deployment script).

Comment: Thanks. This was my issue. Looks like the bootstrap / template has changed since the tutorial was written. In may case there was a serviceWorker.js file - but it was in `/src/` not `/public/`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, for Vue I needed to generate the mockServiceWorker.js in the public directory using the command-line tool as described here:

https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/integrate/browser

This was not clear from the samples to me. Specifically the CLI command to run is:

```
npx msw init ./public
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with React the "Service Worker registration error: Unsupported MIME type ('text/html')" and realised it comes from the index.html directly. This file has a header mime type 'text/html' but the service-worker.js that is loaded via script tag inside has the mime type 'text/javascript'. So the only way was to avoid this error to place into the src folder and import the service-worker.js into the index.js where my App component container was.

Answer (score 1):

For all those who are using `node.js` or `express.js` you might have to add this line in your main `server.js` file (if your service worker file is in the root directory, if it is in some other directory add that path)

```js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"));
```

This is because the `serviceworker.js` is a static file and when you try to register it, `express` tries to find it in static directory that you defined, hence the above line.

Answer (score 0):

The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').

Code for template.js root file

```
export default ({ markup, css }) => {
  return `<!doctype html>
      <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <title>MERN Marketplace</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

          <style>
              a{
                text-decoration: none
              }
          </style>
          <link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json">
        </head>
        <body style="margin:0">
            <div id="root">${markup}</div>
          <style id="jss-server-side">${css}</style>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
          <script>
          if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function() { 
              console.log("Service Worker Registered"); 
            });
          }
          </script>
        </body>
      </html>`;
};
```

Comment: If it's an answer what is first 3 line? And please add more explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and removing other firebase libraries from my config solve the issue for me [Check this on Github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/229#issuecomment-395384687)

```js
// Change this 
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "*********",
    authDomain: "**********",
    databaseURL: "*********",
    projectId: "***********",
    storageBucket: "************",
    messagingSenderId: "***********",
    appId: "************"
};

// To =>
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "*****************",
  projectId: "**********",
  messagingSenderId: "*******",
  appId: "***********"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, service worker file should be on root path. In my case, I cannot use root path, so I redirect service-worker.js to my sub path using apache redirect rule.

```
 RewriteRule "^/service-worker.js$"  "/sub/service-worker.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when hosting a site with python. None of the solutions here worked for me and I came across a [bug posted in chrome dev forum](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=762483) which managed to resolve my issue. Apparently it was windows related issue in my case as the registry entry for .js files had content type set to text/plain due to some previous configuration which I had to change back to application/javascript.

TLDR:

1. Open Registry Editor
2. Go to Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js
3. Change Content Type to application/javascript
4. Restart Chrome and run your site

Hope this helps some one in case none of the above works.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the application (Angular in this case) don't found the file `service-worker.js` (`ngsw-config.js` or every else name file).

I solved the problem by adding in `angular.json`:

```json
"serviceWorker": true,
"ngswConfigPath": "service-worker.json",
```

This should be added to **all configurations**: production, testing and staging, for example.

Answer (score 0):

create serviceWorker.js then paste this code.

```
const CACHE_NAME = 'offline';
const OFFLINE_URL = 'offline.html';


const isLocalhost = Boolean(
    window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
      // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
      window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
      // 127.0.0.0/8 are considered localhost for IPv4.
      window.location.hostname.match(
        /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
      )
  );
  
  export function register(config) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
      const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
      if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
        // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
        // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
        // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2374
        return;
      }
  
      window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;
  
        if (isLocalhost) {
          // This is running on localhost. Let's check if a service worker still exists or not.
          checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);
  
          // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
          // service worker/PWA documentation.
          navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
            console.log(
              'This web app is being served cache-first by a service '
            );
          });
        } else {
          // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
          registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  
  function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register(swUrl)
      .then(registration => {
        registration.onupdatefound = () => {
          const installingWorker = registration.installing;
          if (installingWorker == null) {
            return;
          }
          installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
            if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
              if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
                // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
                // content until all client tabs are closed.
                console.log(
                  'New content is available and will be used when all '
                );
  
                // Execute callback
                if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                  config.onUpdate(registration);
                }
              } else {
                // At this point, everything has been precached.
                // It's the perfect time to display a
                // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
                console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');
  
                // Execute callback
                if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                  config.onSuccess(registration);
                }
              }
            }
          };
        };
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
      });
  }
  
  function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config) {
    // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
    fetch(swUrl, {
      headers: { 'Service-Worker': 'script' },
    })
      .then(response => {
        // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
        const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
        if (
          response.status === 404 ||
          (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)
        ) {
          // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
          navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
            registration.unregister().then(() => {
              window.location.reload();
            });
          });
        } else {
          // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
          registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log(
          'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
        );

        const cache = caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
        const cachedResponse = cache.match(OFFLINE_URL);

        return cachedResponse;
      });
  }
  
  export function unregister() {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.ready
        .then(registration => {
          registration.unregister();
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error.message);
        });
    }
  }
```

and go to your public folder then create offline.html after that import the serviceWorker.js to index.js

```
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
```

at the bottom of index.js paste the code below.

```
serviceWorker.register();
```

Thank you for reading my solution, I hope you fix the problem . Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

for reactjs this work for me

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js">
  if("serviceWorker" in navigator){
        window.addEventListener("load",()=>{
          navigator.serviceWorker.register("%PUBLIC_URL%/serviceworker.js")
          .then((reg)=>{
            console.log("Success",reg.scope)
          }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log("Error",err)
          })
        })
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ngrok

The real problem is that ngrok needs the user to confirm that he is the dev, so to do that they have confirmation screen with a button "continue" which sets a cookie `abuse_interstitial=8d65-bbb-aaa-xx-yyy.ngrok-free.app` but when loading service worker the cookie header is for some reason not added so the html screen is rendered instead with type text/html and it breaks everything. It's not the problem with a setup. The question is how to attach cookies to the request for the service worker.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps worked out for me and resolved the issue.

Move the serviceWorkerRegistration.js file from Public folder to a common folder under src folder.

Register the serviceWorkerRegistration file into the respective location:

```js
let newSw = await navigator.serviceWorker.register(
'/serviceWorkerRegistration.ts'
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {});
```

Add Above code on your service-worker.js file

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note that you've just answered an old question. We usually answer this kind of question if there has been any change in a relevant software version which caused a deprecation of the accepted answer's syntax. If your answer doesn't add new information please consider deleting it.