# firebaseerror: Failed to register a ServiceWorker

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using create-react-app npm to install react js application. I am trying to use firebase in the project. I am following [firebase integration in reactjs](https://medium.com/@akshaypts/magic-mix-of-react-web-app-and-push-notification-using-fcm-bad4191a4987) tutorial. I have done all things correctly. But I am not certain where is webpack config file. I tried inserting

```
const ServiceWorkerWebpackPlugin = require('serviceworker-webpack-plugin');
plugins: [
  ….
  new ServiceWorkerWebpackPlugin({
     entry: path.join(__dirname, './firebase-messaging-sw.js'),
  })
]
```

Above code snippet to node_module/react-scripts/scripts/webpack.config.dev.js. But cannot get working.

I am upto asking for permission to user and after allowing the permission I see the following error.

`browserErrorMessage : "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html')."
code:"messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration"
message:"Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').`

What is the error related to and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can fin the answer explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49566059/service-worker-registration-error-unsupported-mime-type-text-html). What happens is that any requests for unknown text files initially get redirected to index.html, and therefore return with the MIME type of `text/html`. To solve this, you need to catch the service-worker file before it goes to the index by default.