# Problem registering a service worker in React project ( from npx create-react-app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

I hope the question has not been asked too many times.
So, I wanted to create my own service worker file, in my React project.
I called it 'sw.js' and put it in the src/ folder, the same folder that contains the 'index.js' file which contains all the jsx.
The architecture of the React Project is :

- node_modules
  -public
  -src
  -----index.js
  -----sw.js
  -package
  -package-lock
  -README

As soon as the page load, the service worker should register in the browser.
However , on Firefox, I have the following error : 
"Failed to register/update a ServiceWorker for scope ‘http://localhost:3000/’: Bad Content-Type of ‘text/html’ received for script ‘http://localhost:3000/sw.js’.  Must be a JavaScript MIME type."

"Service Worker Error DOMException: "The operation is insecure.""

I know that the error does not com from the code of registering the service worker itself, because it worked on a standard project with no react

here is the code registering the service worker in index.js :

render() {

```
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            console.log('Service Worker and Push is supported');

            navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
                .then(swReg => {
                    console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg);
                    this.setState({ swReg : swReg } )

                    // TODO 3.3a - call the initializeUI() function


                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error('Service Worker Error', err);
                });
        });
    }
```

As you can see, I put it in the render method of my main React component

Comment: Doesn't make sense doing this in render() and you should never directly assign values to `state`

Comment: I have replaced the this.state by this.setState, and I still have the same error. Where can I put my script for registering service workers if I want it to be done automatically ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49566059/service-worker-registration-error-unsupported-mime-type-text-html