# CRA - Failed to register a ServiceWorker, unsupported MIME type ('text/html')

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, service-worker

I am getting the following error when publishing my create react app but the error doesn't appear locally. I recently updated my React version and a load of packages too. I'm guessing it's possibly something to do with that as I've never had this issue before?

```
Error during service worker registration: DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://**subdomain**.azurewebsites.net/') with script ('https://**subdomain**.azurewebsites.net/service-worker.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
```

Any input on this will be greatly appreciated. The error doesn't appear to be breaking anything from what I can see but I'd rather not push this to production with any kind of errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Service Worker registration error: Unsupported MIME type ('text/html')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49566059/service-worker-registration-error-unsupported-mime-type-text-html)

Comment: Possibly.. It could be returning a 404 for service-worker.js... I actually can't see where the service-worker.js file is in my project? Any ideas where I'd find it

Comment: How am I supposed to know where you put your files :D

Comment: ha ha good point...

Comment: For a CRA project **serviceWorker.js** should be in the **src** folder, and it is imported by **index.js** in the same folder. I am surprised though that it is being referenced directly by this file name as is, in production build I would expect it to be bundled in some .js chunk by webpack.

Comment: my index.js references **registerServiceWorker.js** which sits in my **src**... it then tries navgator.serviceWorker.register(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`)... that is where it breaks

Comment: I think your idea with the 404 error is potentially the right way to look after. In the developer's console of your browser, you can see where the file is requested from. Maybe the project isn't even built fully at that point. Compare it to where the file is on your dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out the issue was because I updated the react version. CRA doesn't have service workers out of the box anymore. The project was returning 'unsupported MIME type ('text/html')' because it was hitting 404 looking for a file that doesn't exist.
The fix was relativly simple.
I replaced the `registerServiceWorker()` in my **index.js** file with `reportWebVitals()`. I then added **reportWebVitals.js** to my src folder. (I just created a temp react project and pulled the file from that). After I did that it started to work for me. I think I also had to npm install web-vitals.

Comment: Can you please explain the steps as I am facing the same issues with firebase service worker?